# CAD data not lining up with other data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, cad

I am trying to line up CAD data with a shapefile I have. The shapefile is in NAD 83 PA South feet, and the CAD data is in red below and is in a custom projection NAD 83 Longwood Feet, but the projection is: Rectified_Skew_Orthomorphic_Natural_Origin

As you can see the CAD data comes in much larger and off center. Any ideas how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Is this data available online? Assuming it is the Borneo and Malaya Areas?

Comment: I can see that the units are in Meters? Check the lower right corner of ArcMap in the screenshot.

Comment: @Mapperz Pretty sure this is USA data (Pennsylvania), but a custom coordsys using oblique Mercator.

Comment: It looks like the size is out of whack. Could it be in feet, but the coordinate system thinks it's using meters?